# Modify compile steps of glibc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, glibc, libc

I am trying to recompile the standard Glibc 2.20, with a requirement that I disable optimizations for a few specific components. In particular, I'm looking to remove the -O2 flag that's inherited from the parent make files, to components like saying malloc. Where the standard process of making does gcc malloc.c -O2, I'd want to specify my own command line for this particular module.

Is there a way that can be done?

Comment: It should be posted on https://superuser.com

Comment: @Akshaybarahate It's on topic here (**software tools commonly used by programmers**). Compiler and make questions are [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

In order to compile `malloc/malloc.c` with `-O0`, you can add this to `malloc/Makefile`:

```
CFLAGS-malloc.c = -O0 -D__OPTIMIZE__
```

The `-D__OPTIMIZE__` flag is needed to bypass a check in `include/libc-symbols.h`.  This trick does not work for all parts of glibc, but for `malloc.c`, it produces a working library.